# I need my program to save the location that the user has selected the executable from

Tags: c#, xml, input, save

I am writing a simple launcher for the DayZ server I admin, and one of the prerequisites is that the user needs to choose where their Arma executables are stored, the only problem is, is that after they shut the program down, the settings are lost and need to be reconfigured when they next launch. The code for finding and receiving the path name are as follows:

```c#
public void setArma2PathToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Initialise Open File Dialogue
        OpenFileDialog a2Path = new OpenFileDialog();
        //Allow all files (although user will select .exe)
        a2Path.Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*";

        //if the path is legit
        if (a2Path.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //get the directory and store it to a2Directory, same with a2OA and a3
            a2DirectoryPath = a2Path.FileName;
            a2DirectoryPathModFriendly = Path.GetDirectoryName(a2Path.FileName);

            //and tell the user it's been set
            string a2DirectoryPathString = string.Format("Arma 2 Path set to: {0}", a2DirectoryPath);
            MessageBox.Show(a2DirectoryPathString, "Arma 2 Path", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

    }
```

The ModFriendly bit is due to the way arma handles launch parameters. But this is the part I want to be saved, so that it can be called by this bit of code.

```c#
public void launchArma2EpochChernarus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string modsA2 = "@DayZ_Epoch";
        string ipA2 = "";
        int portA2 = ;


        ProcessStartInfo startA2 = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startA2.Arguments = string.Format("0 0 -skipintro -mod={0} -noSplash -noFilePatching -world=empty -connect={1} -port={2} \"-mod={3};expansion;\"", modsA2, ipA2, portA2, a2DirectoryPathModFriendly);
        startA2.FileName = a2OADirectoryPath;

        // Do you want to show a console window?
        startA2.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startA2.CreateNoWindow = false;
        int exitCode;

        // Run the external process & wait for it to finish
        using (Process proc = Process.Start(startA2))
        {
            proc.WaitForExit();

            // Retrieve the app's exit code
            exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
        }
    }
```

All of the directories are declared further up the program as strings.So after they have selected the file, they have 4 options, one of them uses arma 2, as shown here, and needs to access the Arma 2 exe to start, the problem is, it keeps wiping on reset, so is there any way to store the location for later use ?

Thankyou for reading -
  BorderlineHypeR

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to do it, but you could perhaps save a configuration/text file on the user's computer and search for it.

Comment: There's a lot of ways of doing that, you can write the settings yourself to a text file, you can write to a xml file by serializing objects and loading it when needed.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P432z8q9iVE This is by far the easiest way to save user settings.

Still, I prefer to serialize objects to XML or JSON (using http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), I find it easier when dealing with complex settings (lists, dictionaries etc), but I don't think you would need that for now.